# ¿Cómo crear una tabla en una base de datos de MS-Access usando SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

**Transfondo:**

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que se conecta a una base de datos en MS-Access.

La aplicación que estoy desarrollando está dirigida a diferentes usuarios; cada uno de ellos posee su propia base de datos en Access, por lo que estoy buscando una manera de ejecutar un script similar al siguiente para crear una tabla en una base de datos en Access:

```
CREATE TABLE RewardCoupon
(
    [ID] AUTOINCREMENT,
    [OrderID] INTEGER,
    [PaymentDate] DATETIME,
    [CouponCode] TEXT,
    [CouponType] TEXT,
   [MemberNumber] TEXT
);
```

Al ejecutar el código anterior se origina el siguiente mensaje:

> *Query must have at least one destination field.*

Busco ante todo una **solución en script**; es decir, no quiero contar con que tenga que desarrollar alguna aplicación adicional.

Para efectos de distribución del programa<sup>1</sup>, es necesario contar con un script que facilite la creación de la tabla en cada base de datos en Access que se requiera.

Por lo tanto, mi pregunta es: **¿Cómo crear una tabla en una base de datos de MS-Access usando SQL?**

---

<sup>1</sup> Con esto me refiero a que la persona encargada de dar soporte al programa cuente con los scripts necesarios para *en este caso* ejecutar dicho script y crear rápidamente la tabla en la base de datos en Access.

Comment: ¿Has seleccionado ***"Definición de datos"*** para el tipo de consulta?

Comment: @Aprendiendo.NET honestamente no comprendo, yo básicamente sigo estos pasos: `Crear > Query Design` y allí agrego el SQL. No estoy familiarizado con Access.

Comment: Entonces ese es el problema, está faltando un paso: `Create > Query design > Data definition`. En el siguiente enlace [►](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/create-tables-in-access-2010-using-sql-commands/) tenés un ejemplo, paso a paso, para realizar una consulta de ***"Definición de datos"***

Comment: @Aprendiendo.NET acabo de seguir los pasos, pero no crea la tabla. ¿es posible que _y siento no haberlo mencionado antes, no lo creí relevante_ que no se pueda crear la tabla con estos pasos ya que la base de datos está protegida?

Comment: Puede ser, ***Access 2010*** incorpora muchas mejoras en seguridad. Lo que me llama la atención es que te permita introducir el `script`, estando protegida.

Comment: @Aprendiendo.NET si, al abrir la base de datos, me sale que (es un esquema base de datos de una empresa) _no puedo decir cual_, pero básicamente, al cerrar esa advertencia (que es básicamente un Form), puedo consultar y crear datos. En todo caso, te recomiendo crear una respuesta y la votaré, seguiré ensayando a ver si logro generar la tabla. Tu información es útil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Del [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24334/c%C3%B3mo-crear-una-tabla-en-una-base-de-datos-de-ms-access-usando-sql/57927#comment39476_24334)

> ¿Has seleccionado "Definición de datos" para el tipo de consulta? – Aprendiendo.NET

Síntesis de la respuesta del OP: No.

Del [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24334/c%C3%B3mo-crear-una-tabla-en-una-base-de-datos-de-ms-access-usando-sql/57927#comment39660_24334)

> Entonces ese es el problema, está faltando un paso: Create > Query
>   design > Data definition. En el siguiente enlace [►](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/create-tables-in-access-2010-using-sql-commands/) tenés un
>   ejemplo, paso a paso, para realizar una consulta de "Definición de
>   datos" – [Aprendiendo.NET](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/10998/aprendiendo-net)

---

La solución es correcta; sin embargo, en el caso particular del OP, la base de datos en Access está bloqueada como se puede apreciar en la siguiente *captura de pantalla #1*:

*Captura de pantalla #1*:
[image: Captura de pantalla - base de datos bloqueada]

Para ejecutar el script correctamente, es necesario:

1. Cerrar la ventana modal "marcada con texto rojo" *(según la imagen)*.
2. Habilitar el contenido *(ver captura de pantalla #2)*:

*Captura de pantalla #2*:
[image: Captura de pantalla #2 - habilitar contenido]

3. Es posible que después de este cambio, deba cerrar la base de datos y Microsoft Access para guardar los cambios.
4. Abrir nuevamente la base de datos y realizar los pasos descritos en el enlace.